# Can i work with an asp.net-mvc project to VS 2015 and still have others use it on VS 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, upgrade

I am working on an asp.net-mvc  4 solution  and a we are using VS 2013.  I just got VS 2015 so i wanted to see if i can open up the solution and use VS 2015 going forward while the other team members stay on VS 2013 (they will eventually upgrade but we wanted one person to try and test before everyone else made the move)

Will this work?  Are there any gotchas to worry about?

Comment: I don't think you need to "upgrade" your project.

Comment: Should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, but not always.

A couple of things to keep in mind. During the upgrade process, VS rewrites some of the file paths in the project file and sometimes gets the locations wrong. But, aside from that, most of what the conversion wizard does goes off without a hitch.

And, of course, you want to make sure that both the VS 2015 configuration and the VS 2013 configurations match (references, NuGet packages, versions, etc.).

Intellisense in 2015 is much better. And I've found the publish feature is more robust. Other performance enhancements are most likely due to the move over to Async operations within the program.

I've never heard anyone get nostalgic about 2013 or 2012 once they've moved over to 2015. And the pains are few and far between - well worth the move. :)

Comment: I'm not aware of an upgrade process. Can you provide a before / after proj or sln file that shows this? I'm willing to be wrong but I think I'm right.

Comment: Not all projects are candidates for the upgrade wizard to do its magic. Here's a link from MS that explains the process better than I can: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166539.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. VS 2015 makes some small changes to the project and solution files, but just to make them open in VS 2015 by default, in the case you have multiple versions installed, but they still work perfectly on VS 2013.

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes whatsoever that are forced by opening in 2015. Can you provide a before / after proj or sln file that shows this? I'm willing to be wrong but I think I'm right.

Comment: It may change the header (first line) on the sln file (`Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version xx.xx`). Also, it may change the `ToolsVersion` on the csproj file. But I may be talking about other version that did this, instead of 2015. Not really sure.  =)

Comment: If you create 2010/2012/13 then open with 2015, then close, it does not prompt to save and no changes are made to the sln or proj files. This is from my experience. If you found different, let me know. Would be interesting. In my case no "upgrade" kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

It is a misconception that 2015 has an upgrade that runs on the project or solution files of even 2010 files.

It does not. It will open up these files and make no changes. You can edit the code. Then the developers using the older versions can open up the projects and solutions just fine.

In my experience (and it was using an MVC project), 2015 is totally 2010+ friendly.

Comment: Yes, toddmo, usually this is the case. But not always. Most of the time, VS 2015 creates a separate solution folder (.vs) and solution/project file (.sou) and leaves the originals intact...unless, it (VS 2015) detects that the upgrade wizard needs to be run. Then an upgrade strategy should to be implemented as things go through the wash and into the spin cycle. VS has gotten better with each version with regard to upgrades. Some of the earliest versions were viable hash algorithm candidates :)

Comment: @SRQCoder, ok in my case it never kicked in. I wonder what would cause it to kick in. But the ugliness of previous VS versions' forced upgrade process made all my co-workers not use 2015 at a time that would have been benign to the files and helpful to their careers.